# Definition of Function Composition

Tags: analysis, functions

I am going through Tao's Analysis I and there is a point in Chapter 3 (Set Theory) Section 3.3 (Functions) that I'm not sure about. It's about the composition of functions. I hereby quote directly:

> (Composition) Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be two functions, such that the range of $f$ is the same set as the domain of $g$. We then define the composition $g \circ f : X \rightarrow Z $ of the two functions $g$ and $f$ to be the function defined explicitly by the formula $(g \circ f)(x) := g(f(x)) $. If the range of $f$ does not match the domain of $g$, we leave the composition $g \circ f$ undefined.

What I'm not sure about is why the $R(f)$ must be equal to $D(g)$. Shouldn't it be enough if $R(f) \subseteq D(g)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Tao means by range of $f$ is the co-domain of $f$, not the set $\{f(x):x \in X\}$.

Comment: Yes you're right. The condition to make the composition is that $$f(X)\subseteq \text{dom}(Y).$$